# Same-day Bike Assembly in Budapest

Tags: bicycles, hungary

I'm arriving by plane on a Monday in Budapest, at 10 am. My bike will be in my checked luggage, and will need to be assembled. I want to start biking for another city on Tuesday.

My questions:
**Is it possible to get my bike assembled on the same day?

How much will it cost?

Is there a "go-to" bike shop that I should consider?**

Edit:

Some comments below, suggesting that I should do it myself. I appreciate these comments; I will have tools for the trip, of course, so it is quite possible I can do it myself.

OTOH, I'll be finishing off 15 hours of flying, with a poorly timed lay-over. I'd rather pay a professional 40 Euro to do the job perfectly while I'm having lunch & coffee. And maybe they can store my bike box for a week.

Also, I like bike shops.

Comment: How much assembly is needed? Most people I know can do the assembly themselves as they only twist the handlebars and take off the pedals.

Comment: Even if you go a bit further in disassembly, on most bikes removing/putting back the front wheel is trivial and the back wheel not much more complex (just a better chance of getting your hands dirty as you manipulate the chain). You can in many cases (bikes with quick-release) do everything without any tools (though you should probably have a basic set of tools if you go cross-country).

Comment: And one should have the (fairly simple) tools to disassemble/reassemble the bike for shipping. And you need those for any mechanical issues on the actual bike trip. You aren't pulling major components. On my first bike trip, nearly 50 years, flights were delayed and we finally got into Munich after 10pm so we assembled the bikes and rode off to the campground we intended  to stay at, where of course the reception was closed.

Comment: Why not use this fancy internet thing to look up bike shops either close to the airport, or close to the public transport terminus that you'll be using to get away from the airport. Contact one or two of them to see if they'd be able/willing to accommodate you for a quick assembly upon arrival and if so, how much they'd charge. Some bike shops may be busy enough that they wouldn't be able to do an on-demand, walk-in bike assembly because they've got too much other work in the shop that they've already promised to others...

Comment: Contact the bicycle shop closest to the airport, which is here: https://bikeshopnow.org/hungary/budapest/bike-shop-bp17